# List is Displayed on year having Same Month in Calendar

Tags: android, json, listview, calendar

I have Calendar Widget and below that there is ListView to populate the Event on concerned Month.The List is Displayed on Specific month.But there is one issue on Calendar i.e there are event on **june of 2017** the events are also displayed on june of 2015,2016,2018...........How can this issue be solved?

**MyAdapterCalendar**

```
public class MyAdapterCalendar extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

    private List<Event> list;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyAdapterCalendar(Context context, List<Event> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.calender_student_listitems, list);
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void clearItems(List<Event> list) {
        this.list.clear();
        //  this.list.removeAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        TextView student_calender_date;

    }

    public void addItems(List<Event> list) {
        this.list.clear();
        this.list.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.calender_student_listitems, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_calender_events);
            viewHolder.student_calender_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_calender_date);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getEvents());


        viewHolder.student_calender_date.setText(list.get(position).getRealdate());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**CalenderFragment**

```
 private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL = Navigation_URL;


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String StartDate = jsonObject.getString("StartDate").substring(0, 10);
                                String Title = jsonObject.getString("Title");


                                try {
                                    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(StartDate);

                                    Log.d("Date ", "" + date);
                                    CalendarDay day1 = CalendarDay.from(date);
                                    System.out.println("DAY1" + day1);
                                    Event event = new Event(date, Title, StartDate);
                                    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    cal.setTime(date);
                                    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                                    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                                    if (!map.containsKey(month)) {
                                        List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
                                        events.add(event);
                                        map.put(month, events);


                                    } else {
                                        List<Event> events = map.get(month);
                                        events.add(event);
                                        map.put(month, events);

                                        //Collections.reverse(events);
                                        //rever

                                    }


                                    calevents.add(day1);

                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            }


                            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            // int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            List<Event> event = map.get(month);
                            if (event != null && event.size() > 0)
                                adapter.addItems(event);
                            //Collections.reverse(event);
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            EventDecorator eventDecorator = new EventDecorator(Color.RED, calevents);
                            calendarView.addDecorator(eventDecorator);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }

 @Override
    public void onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date) {


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date.getDate());
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        List<Event> event = map.get(month);


        List<Event> event1 = map.get(year);

        if (event != null && event.size() > 0) {
            adapter.addItems(event);
            // adapter.clearItems(event);
            System.out.println("Adapter" + adapter);

        } else {
            adapter.clearItems(event);
            // event.clear();
        }

      /*  if (event1 != null && event1.size() > 0)
            adapter.addItems(event1);
        else
            adapter.clearItems(event1);
         */

        widget.invalidateDecorators();

    }
```

**Getting image**
[image]

**in here the events are displayed on 2016 june also**
[image]

> How can the list be cleared on date rather than specific date?help is needed

Comment: you can add Another hashmap to Compare year also.try adding another hashmap

Comment: I have added hashmap but it didn't work.How can the year and month are compared at sametime?

Comment: I have added code please take a look at this

Comment: i will try this,and update you

Comment: sure.try and let me know ,if it work or not?

Comment: this doesnot work.Same result as previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try adding this,create hashmap to get year**

```
 private HashMap<Integer, List<Event>> map = new HashMap<>();
    private HashMap<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap();


   try {
                                    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(StartDate);
                                    // Log.d("Date ", "" + date);
                                    CalendarDay day1 = CalendarDay.from(date);
                                    Event event = new Event(date, Title, StartDate);
                                    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    cal.setTime(date);

                                    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                                    System.out.println("MOnth" + month);
                                    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                                    map1.put(year, "");


                                    System.out.println("map1" + map);
                                    if ((!map.containsKey(month)) && (!map.containsKey(year))) {
                                        List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
                                        events.add(event);
                                        map.put(month, events);
                                        map1.put(year, "");


                                        System.out.println("Year" + year);


                                    } else {
                                        List<Event> events = map.get(month);
                                        events.add(event);
                                        map.put(month, events);
                                        map1.put(year, "");
                                        System.out.println("Year" + year);

                                        //Collections.reverse(events);
                                        //rever

                                    }


                                    calevents.add(day1);


                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


    @Override
    public void onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date) {


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date.getDate());
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        List<Event> event = map.get(month);
        String event1=map1.get(year);
        //   List<Event> event1 = map1.get(year);
        System.out.println("OUT" + (event != null && event.size() > 0));

        if ((event != null && event.size() > 0) && (event1 != null )) {
            adapter.addItems(event);
            System.out.println("Adapter" + adapter);


        } else {


            adapter.clearItems(event);
            // event.clear();
        }
        widget.invalidateDecorators();

    }
```

Comment: you also need to change on onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date).Have you changed on this??